# How to add all files in a fileset as an argument to the exec task?

Tags: ant, fileset

I'm trying to provide all *.cpp files in a folder to the c++ compiler through ant.  But I get no further than ant giving gpp a giant string *containing* all the files.  I tried to prove it by using a small test application:

```
int main( int argc, char**args ){
   for( --argc; argc != 0; --argc ) printf("arg[%d]: %s\n",argc,args[argc]);
}
```

With the ant script like this:

```
    <target name="cmdline">
            <fileset id="fileset" dir=".">
                    <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
            <pathconvert refid="fileset" property="converted"/>
            <exec executable="a.exe">
                    <arg value="${converted}"/>
            </exec>
    </target>
```

My a.exe's output is this:

> [exec] arg[1]: .a.cpp.swp .build.xml.swp a.cpp a.exe build.xml

Now here's the question: how do I provide all files in the fileset individually as an argument to the executable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what the [apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task in ANT was designed to support.

For example:

```
  <target name="cmdline">
        <apply executable="a.exe" parallel="true">
            <srcfile/>               
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.cpp"/>
        </apply>
  </target>
```

The *parallel* argument runs the program once using all the files as arguments.

Answer (score 5):

[Found it](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg): the difference seems to lie in `arg value` vs. `arg line`.

```
<arg line="${converted}"/>
```

resulted in the expected output:

```
 [exec] arg[5]: C:\cygwin\home\xtofl_2\antes\build.xml
 [exec] arg[4]: C:\cygwin\home\xtofl_2\antes\a.exe
 [exec] arg[3]: C:\cygwin\home\xtofl_2\antes\a.cpp
 [exec] arg[2]: C:\cygwin\home\xtofl_2\antes\.build.xml.swp
 [exec] arg[1]: C:\cygwin\home\xtofl_2\antes\.a.cpp.swp
```

Comment: small confusion.. did you forget to change `<arg value>` to `<arg line>` in your own answer ?

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: yes... Too excited :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [ant `cpptasks`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/cpptasks/index.html)? This would allow you to integrate C++ compilation into your Ant build in a more Ant-centric fashion. For example, specifying files to be compiled using a fileset.

Here is the example (compatible with Ant 1.6 or later)::

```
<project name="hello" default="compile" xmlns:cpptasks="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib.cpptasks">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="target/main/obj"/>
        <cpptasks:cc outtype="executable" subsystem="console" outfile="target/hello" objdir="target/main/obj">
           <fileset dir="src/main/c" includes="*.c"/>
        </cpptasks:cc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I have; either it's in rigor mortis, or it's dead.  (i.e. it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore).  Do you have experience with it?

Comment: I worked on a mainly-Java project where it was used to build C code using gcc for a few modules. It is still in use there. Note that it is ant-contrib as a whole (rather than cpptasks in particular) which hasn't seen a new release since 2008. If I was reviewing ant-contrib now having not used it before, I guess I would share your concern. However, I think ant-contrib is still widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://w3cgeek.com/converting-an-ant-fileset-to-multiple-apply-args.html), here is the complete code illustrating the use of the [`pathconvert`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task:

```
<target name="atask">
    <fileset dir="dir" id="myTxts">
        <include name="*.txt" />
    </fileset>
    <pathconvert property="cmdTxts" refid="myTxts" pathsep=" " />

    <apply executable="${cmd}" parallel="false" verbose="true">
        <arg value="-in" />
        <srcfile />
        <arg line="${cmdTxts}" />

        <fileset dir="${list.dir}" includes="*.list" />
    </apply>
</target>
```

Above code assumes there are no spaces in the paths.

To support spaces in paths, change above `pathconvert` line to:

```
<pathconvert property="cmdTxts" refid="myTxts" pathsep="' '" />
```

and `arg` line to:

```
<arg line="'${cmdTxts}'"/>
```

Source: [Converting an Ant fileset to multiple apply args](http://w3cgeek.com/converting-an-ant-fileset-to-multiple-apply-args.html).